# Failing to update object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update an object in my order modal, the status is updated correctly but the `latestStatusUpdates` isn't. Here's the important part of my order schema:

```
status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "processing", "delivered", "cancelled"],
    default: "pending",
},
latestStatusUpdates: {
    type: {
        pending: Date,
        processing: Date,
        delivered: Date,
        cancelled: Date,
    },
    default: {
        pending: "",
        processing: "",
        delivered: "",
        cancelled: "",
    },
},
```

Here's how I'm updating the properties:

```
    const orderId = req.params.id;
    const newStatus = req.body.status;
    
    const order = await Order.findById(orderId);

    if (!order) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "Order not found.",
        });
    }

    
    const today = new Date();

    order.status = newStatus; // This is updating correctly

    order.latestStatusUpdates[newStatus] = today; // This is not updating

    await order.save();

    res.status(200).send({
        message: "Order Updated Successfully!",
})
```

Comment: What is `console.log(order.latestStatusUpdates)` just before the `save`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs the correct, updated version, it's just not saving to the db as if await order.save() isn't working on it

Comment: I'm curious, what is `console.log(order.latestStatusUpdates)` _**before**_ `order.latestStatusUpdates[newStatus] = today;`?

Comment: the current value from db, as expected : {
                pending: "",
                processing: "",
                delivered: "",
                cancelled: "",
            }

Comment: If you include [`order.markModified('latestStatusUpdates');`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#dates) before `save`, does it work then?  ... or perhaps by using a deeper path?

Comment: What is `newStatus`? That problematic assignment looks... suspicious to me. Namely why `[newStatus]`?

Comment: I tested your schema and model update code. All properties of `latestStatusUpdates` are updated with a new date correctly. Finding it difficult to recreate the issue. Can you `console.log(req.body.status)`?

Comment: @user20042973 well, each order has a status as shown in the schema, the newStatus is the one sent from the client when you change an order's status to a "new" one
it's also used to update the date of the status that was just chosen to inform the user when that happened. You can understand what's going on if you read the post again

Comment: @jQueeny It's the new status as expected, one of the 4 status shown in the schema

Comment: Strange. What version of mongoose are you using as my defaults are `null` and not "" using your schema on mongoose 7.1.1 `{pending: null, processing: null, delivered: null,cancelled: null,}`.

Comment: This is an old template im editing, the version that shows in the package.json is "mongoose": "^5.13.8"